# How do i check if value is in tolerance based of a value in another cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Does anyone know how i can check if a row of data which contains percentages, to check if its within 10% tolerance based on the the cell which states the target for that row, which in return will change colour in conditional formatting. My goal is if i change the target percentage for any row, the correlating row will highlight which cells are within the 10% tolerance for the specified target percentage. Ive included a picture for reference

[image: example]

Comment: Your verbiage talks of row 1 and row 5.  which of those is supposed to be in row 1 and which in row 5?

Comment: What you are saying is that the data in row 5 is the data to check.  That we need to check that it is below or equal to the tolerance posted in A1?

Comment: Yes @ScottCraner what you said is correct

Comment: @ScottCraner i have better reworded the question

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
=ABS(C2-$B2)<=0.1
```

and apply it to the range `C2:J8`.

[image]